# Add Item details to PayPal Adaptive Payments API

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using the Adaptive Payments API, and am trying
When my user is redirected to the purchase page, under "Description" they see "{My Merchant}'s Test Store".

Any way to change that from hopefully the Pay API call or SetPaymentOptions API call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it.  You need to utilize SetPaymentOptions.

Call Pay with CREATE as the action and then pass the PayKey you get back into SetPaymentOptions to set all the details you want.

Comment: I'm not seeing these options come across onto the purchase page though (unless I set it to DIGITALGOODS)

Comment: Would need to see samples of your API requests to try and reproduce what you're doing and see if I can find the problem.